# Why does Windows assign different file permissions to files on exFAT and FAT32 filesystems?

Tags: linux, windows, file-permissions

The question in the title describes what I *think* is going on, but there are a few moving parts here. I was trying to copy two directories, namely `folder_one` and `folder_two`, from a Windows machine to a Linux machine.

I took the following steps:

1. One the Windows machine, used the GUI 7-Zip program to compress `folder_one` to `folder_one.7z` in the desktop folder.
2. Copied `folder_one.7z` to a USB drive that was formatted **(from Linux)** as FAT32.
3. Removed the USB drive from the Windows machine.
4. Copy `folder_one.7z` from the USB drive to `~/tmp` on the Linux machine.

Now, I repeated the same steps for `folder_two`, but step 2 failed because `folder_two.7z` ended up being larger than 4 GB (the filesize limit for FAT32). So, I reformatted the USB drive **(from Windows)** as exFAT, copied `folder_two.7z`, and completed the remaining steps the same way.

After this operation, running `ls -l` in `~/tmp` from the Linux machine reveals that the larger folder has executable positions enabled for everyone while the smaller one doesn't:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 max max 1.9G Feb 11  2023 folder_one.7z
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 max max 5.8G Feb 11  2023 folder_two.7z
```

**Why might this be?** The only difference between the two files is that they were moved from Windows to Linux on different kinds of file systems (different in both kind and in which OS was used to format them). Is it simply that FAT32 doesn't support executable permissions at all?

Comment: That's it precisely - FAT32 doesn't support file permissions :-) I think it allows creating read-only files, but no user/group-based r/w/x exists.

Comment: I disagree. :)
FAT32 supports file permssions, however, permissions only allow for a simple "write protection" switch for files...

Comment: @r2d3 - thanks for confirming, nice to know I'm not completely demented yet :-D

Comment: Sorry, Peregrin069, I apoligize for my dumb posting.
I strongly confirm that I can't see any signs of being demented. :)

Comment: So, what we are seeing here is simply the difference between the "default" Linux permissions `rw-r--r--` and the "default" Windows permissions `rwxr-xr-x`. Why the difference? Why would Windows mark files as executable by default? (I would've assumed this not to be the case, given the rigamarole Windows normally puts you through with "enter your password to run this .exe")

Comment: Windows has no "mark" for executables, it does this by the file-extension. The difference is probably because Linux permissions are so different from Windows that they can be mistranslated, which happened here for exFAT..